How can I set a tag when a user registers in wordpress via gravity forms
Users are registering on my site via gravity form. When they register, they select the type of user they will register as. For example, "Are you a Cat?" or  "Are you a Dog?".
I would like to set a tag for the registered user if "Cat" or "Dog" depending on the selection.
The code I have tried (along with some variations) is located below.
add_action('gform_user_registered', 'assign_user_tag_based_on_user_type', 10, 4);
function assign_user_tag_based_on_user_type($user_id, $feed, $entry, $user_pass) {
    // Get the value of the radio button field (ID 8)
    $user_type = rgar($entry, '8'); // '8' is the field ID for the "Are you a Cat or a Dog?" question

    // Check the value and assign the appropriate tag
    if ($user_type === 'Dog') {
        wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 'Dog', 'user_tag', true); // "Dog" tag applied when "Dog" is selected
    } elseif ($user_type === 'Cat') {
        wp_set_object_terms($user_id, 'Cat', 'user_tag', true); // "Cat" tag applied when "Cat" is selected
    }
}

I've attempted a number of variations for the code but it never works. Any help is greatly appreciated.
